# Insert into SQL Server using @temp table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to check if something like this is possible. I have a table variable with just `Yes` and `No`. I want to create a select query using this (basically cross join) , and than use this select query to insert all the data in a table

```
DECLARE @testTable TABLE (testTable nvarchar(3))

INSERT INTO @testTable VALUES ('Yes')
INSERT INTO @testTable VALUES ('No')

INSERT INTO DimLifeEventFlags_Stage_1
(
Select 
    LET.ID AS eID,
    LERS.ID AS cID,
    DYLE.testTable AS testTable
from 
    mainTable1 LERS, 
    mainTable2 LET , 
    @testTable DYLE
    )
```

Comment: yes you are doing good :)

Comment: If you want to cross join some data with other data, yes, you can do it.

Comment: Tip: You can insert multiple rows in one statement, e.g. `insert into @TestTable values ( 'Yes' ), ( 'No' );`.

Answer (score 1):

There no reason you can't do what you're doing but if I were writing this I would Use CROSS JOIN join to be explicit. CROSS JOIN also makes it easier if your mixing in LEFT or INNER joins.

I would also not use the temp table at all and instead use the values clause

```
INSERT INTO DimLifeEventFlags_Stage_1
(
Select 
    LET.ID AS eID,
    LERS.ID AS cID,
    DYLE.testTable 
from 
    mainTable1 LERS  
    CROSS JOIN mainTable2 LET 
    CROSS JOIN (Values ('Yes'), 
                        ('No') 
                ) as DYLE (testTable )
    )
```